# What does it mean when you lose your hat?

Tags: fistful-of-frags

In the new standalone version of the game on Steam, I've seen people get their hat shot off their head in this game, sometimes I even do it without realizing, and sometimes my own hat gets shot off quite unexpectedly.

But, I have no idea what it relates to in-game.  Near as I can tell it doesn't have to do with headshots, because I recall doing this with pistols, which I do not think get damage bonuses for headshots.

So what does it mean when I lose my hat?  And, as a secondary question, do I get my hat back if I drink enough whiskey?

Comment: +1 - haven't played the game and yet this question makes me want to. -  _do I get my hat back if I drink enough whiskey?_

Comment: @Flaunting It's free, so by all means give it a try.  Also, be sure to press x-4. This is very important.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just like the western cliché where someone shoots a cowbow in the hat and it flies away, this is just a visual candy to add some authenticity and fun to the game. It also means that you were a bit off regarding your headshot and aimed a bit too high and shot the hat only (you should be able to shoot a hat with any gun and even [your fists](http://youtu.be/EwH2KDBTurU?t=1m37s)). As far as I'm aware of, drinking whiskey only gives back HP, you can only get your hat back when you respawn.

Comment: So unlike in TF2, you CAN get shot in the hat?

Comment: @Zibbobz yes you can shot the hat only :) (see [the 3rd screenshot of this article for example](http://www.pcgamer.com/2014/05/25/mod-of-the-week-fistful-of-frags/))

Comment: This isn't true. Shooting a hat off gives you points, see update notes: http://steamcommunity.com/games/fof/announcements/detail/220995703612406598

Comment: The comment was correct at the time of posting, however.

Answer (score 2):

After reading some update information from [the steam page](http://steamcommunity.com/games/fof/announcements/detail/220995703612406598) for FoF updates, it appears that hats flying off actually mean something now.

From the page:

> New feature: hat-shot.
>
> As you know, **hats fall now when hitting head, so it's completely related to damage.** This feature will continue the same, but an additional way to drop hats will be added.
>
> A hat-shot will be feasible by just **shooting at enemy's hat, without causing any damage.** It just requires a new hitbox that covers the hat area.
>
> And what do you gain by dropping other people hats, may you wonder? Just the pleasure of seeing some poor hat-less bastard? No, **it will grant some extra notoriety**, so to speak, it allows some extra depth as players may wanna drop enemies hat before giving them a ticket to hell. Please watch this video if you wanna check a movie version of it.
>
> Additionally, a **new achievement** will be added that consist into dropping a few other player's hats without causing any damage, during same life.